# Multiplication evaluates with asterisk at the end when creating an .xls with PHP

Tags: php, xls

The title might be a little confusing, but I've got a spreadsheet generator, and in this case it's used to generate a spreadsheet to upload to Amazon, and I'm working on converting the price of the items from USD to CAD.

In my file, I store the price of my items into $price_amazon, then I multiply it by whatever the user enters and gets stored into itself. Like so;

```
$conversion = $row['rate'];
$price_amazon = $row['price'];

$price_amazon = $price_amazon*$conversion
#Evaluates to:
#19.99*1.24
```

Here's the issue, once the spreadsheet loads up, my price fields will have the correct value, in this case 24.7876 but with an asterisk at the end, so 24.7876*. All of the cells for prices have an asterisk at the end, and I'm not sure on what is going on exactly. The image below shows exactly what I'm talking about, taken directly from the spreadsheet.

[image: asterisk]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then just remove the asterix at the end of the string and convert the value to a float:

```
$price_amazon = (float) substr($row["price"], 0, -1);
```

or even just a type conversation to a `float` removes the asterix from the end:

```
$price_amazon = (float) $row["price"];
```

Comment: It seems like what you suggests only hides the underlying problem, it does not correct it.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to help me out! I forgot  to mention that I already tried to use substr to no avail. It simply removes the last NUMBER while the asterisk still remains. I'm starting to think it's something with Excel and not my script. The cell in Excel is in-fact a value and not a formula or equation. Also, just noticed your edit, the problem occurs after the multiplication, when I remove it and just put $price_amazon into a cell, it works flawlessly. Once I multiply it by a user-entered value or even a static one that I set, I get an asterisk at the end of the value.

Comment: So the **result** of your multiplication is in-fact a _string_? Did you tried to `var_dump` the variables to check where the asterix's coming from?

Comment: @Spingolini It was all user error! See my answer that I left to the question to see how much of a noob I am. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't saw you've edited the comment. I'm glad I could help you and you've figured out the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Figured out the problem. User error! Further down my script, where I'm echoing all the variables into their necessary cells, I fat-fingered the asterisk key attempting to do God-knows-what. Here's what it looked like

```
echo "<table>\n";
echo "<tr>
<td>$price_amazon*</td>
```

As you can see, such a very easy mistake to make and hard to find, but this was definitely a case of user error. I appreciate everyone taking the time to help resolve my issue when in the end, the issue was me!